# Is there a way to trace syscalls without disabling SIP?

Tags: python, dtrace, open-source, command-line, macos

I'm trying to optimize a local Python script and I'd like to see syscalls etc.

`dtruss` seems like a great tool for that, but I get a series of errors when I run it that I think are related to SIP being enabled.

Also, it exits very quickly (versus > 1min run time) which I think has to do with not being able to use its `-R` flag when root (which I obviously have to be in order to run `dtruss`).

Comment: It seems like you can run dtruss with SIP enabled, but it involves some hoops. see https://poweruser.blog/using-dtrace-with-sip-enabled-3826a352e64b. Not posting as an answer, b/c I haven't tried it myself.

Comment: @JonWolski thanks!